# Could a campaign become demotivating, if there are too many options?

Tags: dnd-5e, adventure-writing

For our last session I decided to put in a sidequest for my group expecting them to just finish it as they get it.

But they were in different interests, while some of the characters (or actually the players?) wanted to do the side quest, others didn't realize it and aimed for the main quest line. Luckily, the group decided to collectively finish the side quest first, leaving me not to worry about it. But this made me rethink the way I was planning to design the campaign after this adventure finishes.

In the progress of the current adventure, the characters will acquire shares of a business. Where in the next adventure, on some occasions I'm planning to make a side quest which requires actions whose outcome has an impact on the business. Also the adventure itself has 2 main questline(ish) events that will later interweave. But at all this would mean the group has (in the beginning at any point) at least 2 primary quests to do, while there sometimes might be even a 3rd semi-optional quest which also shouldn't be ignored for too long.

So as the last time the party was on a point, they had to decide how to go on between just 2 options and it felt to me more like a discussion as like a game, I'm now worried:

Is this adventure design fine to go with for DnD5e?
Or are there any design problems that could reasonably cause moments of dissatisfaction in the adventure, caused by too many choices of the ways to take?

Comment: I'm having a great deal of trouble parsing this question. I get the impression that your players aren't sure what to do next, and are asking you for more information, and you consider this to be a problem... Maybe?

Answer (score 6):

I've DMed in a lot of different ways over the years, and I love building sandboxes, but often players get confused and lost if there are too many options.  I've evolved a way of keeping the sandbox feel, which make the world feel real and evolving around the players, and keep my own sanity for preparation and the players not feeling overwhelmed, in a few simple ways:

1. I pepper the world with things that *could* be entry points for quests or adventures (plot coupons).  The barmaid that looks troubled....that mysterious scroll you found in the last dungeon....the weird laws in the last town you entered...the goal being that all of these things are out there, but aren't things I'm actively pushing towards (see point 2).  At any point the players could get curious about them, and spend time investigating them (and I'd be ready to roll down that pathway) but they won't pick up on most of them, and won't care about most of them.
2. Give the players options when they feel lost.  I like to recap the last session by bookending it with their motivations.  E.g. When we last played the party was investigating X. *insert action recap here.* So what do you want to do?  Continue further into the dungeon to try to find X,  or escort the prisoners you've found back to safety?     Now, they can definitely do anything else and I'm not railroading them, I'm just reminding them of their options (and usually whatever they discussed last time to get the discussion going again).  If it comes to a point where the party is just undecided and can't make up their mind (happens more with new players) I'll remind them of one of the many plot coupons they have picked up. (e.g. They are worried about fighting the dragon they know is ahead, so I remind them that they just picked up a strange dwarven sword, and the smith in the last town seemed to know a lot about runesmithing).

For your  particular concerns with the business, I would make it a set piece that generates x money every week/month.  Eventually the players will want it to generate more, in which case you tell them about ways to do it (quests).  Alternatively, if you really want them to focus on their business, have them go to collect their money one day and find the windows smashed in or boareded up, and the workers scared because they had been robbed (or have the guard come and question the players because of the same).

Comment: yeah, I was going to make the buisiness a kind of passive pet. And since they are jsut holding a share while some one else ist the real owner of that business, I'll let him just on soem ocassions inform them about how is business going and if the players feel they want to change it they can jsut do that by interacting with the NPC while some times he will ask them for obtaining/or investigating stuff, what im planing to eventually unlock new features

Answer (score 3):

First this kind of issue has nothing to do with the game/system you're using, so don't worry about it.

If you noticed your players feel a bit lost in front of the choice they're given, it's maybe not because of the number of options (I mean, 3 options doesn't seems too hard to handle), but because they don't understand what they imply.

Make sure they fully understand what is at stake with each option. If the outcome of following a quest line is unpredictable (because you want to hide it, or because you don't know it yourself yet), make sure that they at least have a very good reason to take this path (and that every player is aware of it).

If you have already done that, then there is 2 possibilities :

- Your players are enjoying the discussion and the choice-making involved, because they enjoy being confronted to a dilemma.
- They don't.

In either cases, adapt yourself : let them discuss and plan, or remove some choices and make your adventure a bit more linear. Be sure to discuss with them about this issue to know what their preference is.

Comment: Thats was probably the case. the side quest was unpredictable in outcome for them as they just had a hint and had to decide to follow it or don't do it yet. Maybe that was just the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible for players to get lost in a sea of too many options.  Whether that happens depends a lot on the players.  Some players simply do not want that, and want to be channeled-- *not railroaded*-- into a narrative.  But it depends on the GM and the structure of the world, as well.  The more side-questy and sand-boxy a game becomes, the more agency the characters have.  If a GM wants to run a side-questy or sand-boxy game, that puts certain requirements on GM, his world-building, his plotting, and his pacing.

The big two things I have learned through playing and GMing that style of game are:

1)  High character agency simply *requires* that the players have a good understanding of the environment.  In order to form plans or recognize side-quests (for instance, a side-quest that might benefit their business venture) they simply *must* understand the world well enough to tentatively predict its responses:  "We have Problem A.  Those guys can solve it but they have Problem B.  We can solve Problem B."

This often sounds simple in the GM's had.

But this is often the opposite of how the players actually feel, especially if you are in a home-brew world.  This is where genre adaptations become very useful-- if you're playing in a game based off some established universe, your players need only master (and you need only communicate) your differences from the baseline.

If you're not able, or don't want, to do an adaptation, you will almost certainly have to ease your players into this.  In a transition phase, you might want to have a mentor figure or two, as NPCs, whose main narrative purpose is to prompt the PCs to start thinking in terms like this.

And then in the mid-game, you kill them.

2)  Figure out what to do if your players don't figure out what to do.

Sometimes this is just giving them something concrete to do.

But the best technique I have for sand-boxy games is to figure out the general sweep of what the game world will do if the players don't act or don't figure out what to do.  Generally, it should be something they don't like.  Generally, it should be something that provokes a more obvious response from the characters.

Characters missed several side-quests that would have let them defend the village from orcs?  Okay, orcs raid the town.  Players ignore this?  Okay, orcs *sack* the town.  The game world should go on with its own internal logic, and since most games have a default assumption of heroic PCs, that internal logic should require heroic opposition.

But, that said, it's important not to make this a dark shadow of rail-roading-- it's a good idea to give several ways to learn about the impending orc invasion, and several ways to deal with it.  Otherwise, the players are not only on rails, they are on rails they can't easily see and they are punished for mis-steps.